# How to re-register (or remove) an existing Mongoose schema/model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Complicated issue, and one that I doubt many people have to run into... but I'm trying to manage schemas dynamically post-runtime, as in update/replace schemas that have already been loaded.  Basically an app that lets you create, register, and later update schemas (to then populate).  Of course, trying to redefine a schema that's already been registered results in this error:

`OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite [myModelName] model once compiled.`

Is there any way to destroy a mongoose Model/Schema once it's been created?  I've checked the API docs and searched for answers to no avail.  Creating new schemas on the fly works like a champ - but updating them throws me against the brick wall.

Would rather not fork mongoose to add this functionality if I can at all help it :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That is a fair enough question. It may also help to show some (even failing) code. Also give example usage, as there may be a different approach to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

> delete mongoose.connection.models[myModelName];

and then re-register/re-initialize it . it will work fine